# C# Contains Method

Tags: c#, contains, viewbag

My site has a column that displays the news. The DIV-s with these news which contain the word "prize" must be painted in the green color. (If a person has created a record (a news) without specifying the Prize (without word "Prize"), the green is not necessary. But if a person filled out the field model.Prize (so in the text we have a word "Prize") the div must be painted in green color.

In a view for creating news there is a field `model.Prize`

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Prize,4,55,null)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prize)
</div>
```

The value of model.Prize takes the Controller which create a new news record.

```
public ActionResult Create(Project project)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {(some code...)
        News n = new News();
        n.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        n.Description = project.Shortdescription+"\r\n\Prize:\r\n"+project.Prize;

       (some code…)
       NewsController.Add(db,n);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Main");
   }
```

In the another method Block of News Controller I display the news:

```
public PartialViewResult Block()
{
    List<News> news = new List<News>();
    Int32 count = 0;

    foreach (News n in db.News.ToList().OrderByDescending(n => n.Date))
    {
        if (count++ < 13) news.Add(n);
    } 
    return PartialView(news);
```

For each entry in the View Block creates `<div class ="newsWrapper">` in which the news record insert.

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
    <div class ="newsWrapper">
    <p class="newsDate">@item.Date.AddHours(4).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")</p>
    <a href="@item.Link"> @item.Title </a>
    <p>@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(item.Description).Replace("\n", "<br />"))</p>
</div> 
}
```

I tried to solve the problem
I added the new div in the Block View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{   
<div class ="newsWrapper">
        <div class="@(ViewBag.IsPrize == true ? "GreenNewsClass" : "")">
            <p class="newsDate">@item.Date.AddHours(4).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")</p>
                <a href="@item.Link"> @item.Title </a>
            <p>@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(item.Description).Replace("\n", "<br />"))</p>
        </div>
</div>
}
```

The `GreenNewsClass` will paint this div in green color.

But how can I get `ViewBag.IsPrize == true` if `n.Description` contains the word Prize, 
and `ViewBag.IsPrize == false` if it's not?

I tried to change the method Block:

```
public PartialViewResult Block()
{
    List<News> news = new List<News>();
    Int32 count = 0;

    foreach (News n in db.News.ToList().OrderByDescending(n => n.Date))
    {
        if (count++ < 13) news.Add(n);
        if (n.Description.Contains("Призы"))
        {
            ViewBag.IsPrize = true;
        }
        else { ViewBag.IsPrize = false; }
    }  
    return PartialView(news);
```

but it paints all news in green color, not only those which contain the word Prize.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{   
  <div class ="newsWrapper">
    <div class="@(item.Description.Contains("Призы") ? "GreenNewsClass" : "")">
      <p class="newsDate">@item.Date.AddHours(4).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")</p>
      <a href="@item.Link"> @item.Title </a>
      <p>@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(item.Description).Replace("\n", "<br />"))</p>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: @Dylan you should mark this as the correct answer then so future readers can use it.

Answer (score 1):

First  try to add a property to your model instead to your `ViewBag`, it seems like you only have a single value in your `ViewBag`.

Remove the `true` condition because it's redundant, move the class definition inside the condition that way the div will be empty when the condition is false
and try the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{   
    <div class ="newsWrapper">
        <div @(item.IsPrize? "class=GreenNewsClass" : "")>
            <p class="newsDate">@item.Date.AddHours(4).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")</p>
            <a href="@item.Link"> @item.Title </a>
            <p>@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(item.Description).Replace("\n", "<br />"))</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have not verified the code but try it out.